# Warning message: In dbFetch(rs, n = n, ...) : error while fetching rows

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, rmysql

I am fetching data from MySql using R and getting `Warning message: In dbFetch(rs, n = n, ...) : error while fetching rows` error. I need to understand how can I fetch the data in batches to avoid such error.

My Code:

Df<-

```
ColId       Range
IOP-22      232
IOP-23      234
```

Where datafrme consist around ~20000 entries, and passing `ColId` to MySql query:

```
get_dt<-paste0("select ColId,col1, col2, col3 from mytable where ColId IN (", paste(shQuote(Df$ColId , type = "sh"),
                                                     collapse = ', '), ");")
```

Comment: The error message isn't very helpful. Have you checked the example in `?DBI::dbFetch`. You need to make sure to use `dbClearResult()` after `dbFetch()`.